# Integration Testing against a service in docker

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, docker, docker-compose

I have a microservice which I am testing (Java maven project with JUnit). This has a dependency on another microservice. I am writing an e-2-e system test and want to spin up the external service from a Docker image for a full automated test.

My question is what is the best way to have a maven project spin up a docker image instance which can then be used in an automated test suite?

At the moment I a using maven-exec plugin to call a shell script during the integration-phase which starts the docker container. It may not be the most elegant solution, and I also have no way of knowing when the container is ready.

Any thoughts or help would be appreciated.

Please note: This is for full system testing against real services so I don't want to mock or stub the external service.

Comment: MIght be worth considering: https://www.testcontainers.org/

Comment: Have you considered using `docker-compose`, with Maven as your entry point in one container, and the other(s) running the dependent service(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Spotify maven plugin](https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin#testing) for docker or [Fabric8 maven pluign](https://github.com/fabric8io/docker-maven-plugin)

Fabric8 has goals as build, run and stop. This may not help you knowing if a container is ready for testing. (Could you have a sort of ping service in your test code that suspended tests until you got a OK 200?)

Comment: You can [wait](https://dmp.fabric8.io/#start-wait) for some condition on the container in order to determine if it's ready for tests. [Here](https://github.com/llorllale/youtrack-api/blob/master/pom.xml#L345-L365) is a sample configuration that sends HTTP 'pings' and waits for a specific HTTP response code back.

Comment: @MikeJ glad to hear it fit your needs :)